# How to compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \log (1+\frac{2i}{n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-integration

I was asked this series

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \log \left( 1+\frac{2i}{n} \right) $$

I tried to use Riemann sum

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \log \left( 1+\frac{2i}{n} \right)
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{1}^{n} \log(1+2x) \, \mathrm{d}x $$

But the answer is divergent.
What is wrong here?

Comment: What are the bounds for the integral ?

Comment: from 1 to n .Sorry I forget to type the bound.

Comment: Not at all ! Check your notes .

Comment: If $1 \leq i \leq n$, then $\frac1n \leq \frac{i}{n} \leq 1$.  It's $i/n$, not $i$, that corresponds to $x$ in your Riemann integral.

Answer (score 4):

When you write an integral $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ into a Riemann sum, what you essentially do is: you partition the interval $[a,b]$ into $n$ segments, each of length $h:=(b-a)/n$ and you sum up the area of the rectangles formed by the partition that converges to the integral when the partition is made finer by letting $n\to\infty$. Thus, $$\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}hf(a+ih)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n hf(a+ih)$$ where $h:=(b-a)/n$ is the width of each partition segment. The sum from $0...(n-1)$ is the lower Riemann sum and the one from $1...n$ is the upper Riemann sum.

[image: Riemann sum]

Now, a question to you: what should $a,b$ be for your problem so that $h:=\frac{b-a}n$ equals $1/n$ and the term $f(a+ih)$ in the summation equals $f(i/n)$? And after that, what choice of $f(x)$ fits such that $f(i/n)$ equals the summation term $\log\left(1+2\cdot\frac in\right)$ in your problem?

Comment: Be careful.  Your diagrams are correct, but your descriptions of upper/lower Riemann sums are inconsistent with those diagrams; rather, you describe what is commonly called the left/right, not the lower/upper, Riemann sums.  They agree only for increasing functions $f$.

Comment: I got it! a = 0 and b = 1. And f(x) = log(1+2*x) .So, the answer will be integral f(x) from 0 and 1.